# How to use Typescript enum that was exported from a .d.ts file?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript-typings

I have a tool that auto generates types (graphql codegen). In the generated type definition file, it exports an enum

```
 export enum DevicesSortField {
  Name = 'NAME',
  ConfigurationStatus = 'CONFIGURATION_STATUS',
  Connectivity = 'CONNECTIVITY'
}
```

If I try to use the enum in some way in my ts file, such as switch case on all the cases, I get a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error at runtime. This is because it tries to import the d.ts file from the js transpiled code. However, there are no typings files that can be seen according to the js code! Normally, string enums are converted into objects when they're transpiled, but I guess theres different behaviour if the enum is in a .d.ts file. How do i get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to my codegen.yml:

```
enumsAsTypes: true #needed to be able to compare enum cases in resolvers (since we are using a .d.ts)
```

so the file looks like this:

```
overwrite: true
schema: "src/components/**/schema.ts"
documents: null
generates:
  src/typings/graphql-auto-codegen.d.ts:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-resolvers"
    config:
      useIndexSignature: true #fixes https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/1133
      contextType: ./context#LockhartContext
      enumsAsTypes: true #needed to be able to compare enum cases in resolvers (since we are using a .d.ts)
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
constEnums: true
```

in config section.